# Represent the motion of a particle

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, animation

I am trying to represent the motion of a particle along a given trajectory. So I defined the following functions

```
x[t_] := Cos[t]

y[t_] := Sin[t]

T[t_] := {x[t], y[t]}

Trajectory = ParametricPlot[T[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, ImageSize -> Large,AspectRatio -> 1];

P[t_] := Point[T[t]]

V[t_] = Arrow[{T[t], T[t] + {x'[t], y'[t]}}];
```

and so I give the command

```
Animate[Show[Trajectory, Graphics[V[t], P[t]]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

but unfortunately the final result is really stranger and moreover I do not see the point P in the motion but only the velocity vectors and the trajectory that strangely changes its size. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: If you indend by 4spaces your code is shown (I edited your question accordingly)

Comment: Fix ``Show`` by adding ``PlotRange`` and wrapping ``V[t]`` and ``P[t]`` into a list: ``Show[Trajectory, Graphics[{V[t], P[t]}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]``.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Okay, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Domen Okay, it works for a circumference but strangely it does not work for a parabol, e.g. try to put x[t_]:=t, y[t_]:=t^2.

Comment: @Domen E.g. see this
x[t_] := t
y[t_] := t^2
T[t_] := {x[t], y[t]}
Trajectory = 
  ParametricPlot[T[t], {t, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
P[t_] := Point[T[t]]
V[t_] = Arrow[{T[t], T[t] + {x'[t], y'[t]}}];
Animate[Show[Trajectory, Graphics[{V[t], P[t]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 25}}], {t, 0, 5}]

Comment: Where is the mistake?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro, you should manually adjust the ``PlotRange`` so that the whole image fits. For the parabola, just use a larger range, such as ``PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 40}}``.

Comment: Oh yeah, I saw: so is not possible to draw only the part of the parabola where effectively the point P run?

Comment: Oh, forget it! I have successfull: the value of t must be the same in the trajectory and in the animate. so thanks very much for your assistance!!! See you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Trajectory =ParametricPlot[T[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, ImageSize -> Large,AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 1.5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];

P[t_] := Point[T[t]]

V[t_] := Arrow[{T[t], T[t] + {x'[t], y'[t]}}];

Animate[Show[{Trajectory, Graphics[{V[t], P[t]}, PlotRange -> 1.5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 300], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

The same algorithm works for any possible motion: anyway the value of t in Trajectory and in Animate must be only one and moreover the PlotRange in Animate must be adjusted conveniently